# Accessing the EntityManager in an @Aspect for a JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to follow the advice from [1](https://medium.com/@Integral_io/elegant-multi-tenancy-for-microservices-part-iii-implementation-supporting-infrastructure-64b74093615), to implement discriminator column based multi-tenancy using Hibernate interceptors and filters in Spring Boot 2.0.5. So far the Interceptor is working, however I want to apply the Hibernate filter directly on Spring Data JPA Repositories. The aspect I wrote looks like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TenantAwareRepositoryAspect {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Before("execution(* com.example.tenant.jpasupport.TenantAwareRepository+.*(..))")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        entityManager
            .unwrap(Session.class)
            .enableFilter(TENANT_FILTER_NAME)
            .setParameter(TENANT_ID_PROPERTY_NAME, TenantHolder.getTenantId());
    }
}
```

I then add the `TenantAwareRepository` as a marker interface to the repositories that contain Tenant-scoped entities.

Now: My tests of the repositories using the @DataJpaTest annotation run through just fine, but when I start the app and try to fetch some data I am getting a `IllegalStateException` with message **"No transactional EntityManager available"**. I have an `@EnableTransactionManagement` on my app configuration.

I am guessing I need to access the excact EntityManager that is used in the generated Spring Data Repository, but how do I get that in the aspect?

Comment: Inject the `EntityManagerFactory` using `@PersistenceUnit` and use `EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(this.emf)` to get the correct `EntityManager`. Also make sure that your transactional boundary is the service and not the repository and that you order this aspect to execute AFTER the transactional aspect.

Comment: Thanks! Switching to the `EntityManagerFactory` is seemingly not important, however following up on the second hint about the transactional boundary, I have found one method in the Service class where the @Transactional annotation has been missing  and now it's working . I am now trying to make this less brittle by trying to enforce that a transaction is required or else opened here, but putting an `@Transactional` on the `before` method in the aspect just gets ignored.

Answer (score 2):

try to inject **EntityManagerFactory** instead of **EntityManager**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TenantAwareRepositoryAspect {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Before("execution(* com.example.tenant.jpasupport.TenantAwareRepository+.*(..))")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(entityManagerFactory)
            .unwrap(Session.class)
            .enableFilter(TENANT_FILTER_NAME)
            .setParameter(TENANT_ID_PROPERTY_NAME, TenantHolder.getTenantId());
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, the filter is not being activated anymore and my @DataJpaTest for tenant isolation fails. Probably because it is not the EntityManager that is used in the Repository.

Comment: This won't work as this will create a new `EntitiyManager` instead of reusing the thread bound `EntityManager`. Hence it simply won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum, you are right, my mistake, i should use **EntityManagerFactoryUtils**

Comment: Actually the issue has been that I have had a new Service method that was not annotated with `@Transactional` which meant that the injected `EntityManager` was not actually in a transaction which seems to be required for Hibernate Filters to work. Still, I am considering accepting your answer if anyone can explain to me why getting the `EntityManger` through `EntityManagerFactoryUtils` in combination with `EntityManagerFactory` is still important even though the thread-bound `EntityManager` seems to be injected with `@Autowired` just fine.